# calculator in angular js using directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular js and trying to build a calculator. My requirement is that I need two separate directives each for textbox (to display) and for buttons.

The problem is that I'm getting the result, but the text box is not getting updated.

Below is the code that I have written.

**Script File :**

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);


    app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
        var showInput = '0';

        return {
            getProperty: function () {
                return showInput;
            },
            setProperty: function(value) {
                showInput = value;
            }
        };
    });


app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,sharedProperties) {

    $scope.count = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','-','*','/','=','C'];       $scope.showInput2 = sharedProperties.getProperty();

}); app.directive("textdir",function() {    return {    restrict : 'E',     template : "<input type ='text' value='{{showInput2}}' id='txt'><br/>"      }; });

app.directive('counter',

  function() {

    return {

      restrict: 'EAC',

      template: '<div>'+
          '<button ng-repeat="i in internalCount" ng-click="kick(i)">{{i}}</button>'+
         '</div>',

      scope: {

                internalCount: '=model'

            },    controller : function($scope,sharedProperties)      {
          $scope.op1="";
          $scope.op2="";
          $scope.tempStr="";
          $scope.isContinue = true;
          $scope.showInput1 = sharedProperties.getProperty();

          $scope.kick = function(clickvalue)
          {
                switch(clickvalue)
                {
                    case "=":
                        if ($scope.tempStr != "" && $scope.op1!= "") 
                        {
                            if($scope.op2=="")
                            {

                                $scope.showInput1 = $scope.clac($scope.tempStr, $scope.showInput1, $scope.op1); 


                            }
                            if(($scope.op1=="*"||$scope.op1=="/") && $scope.op2=="-")
                            {
                                $scope.showInput1 = -$scope.showInput1;
                                $scope.showInput1 = $scope.clac($scope.tempStr, $scope.showInput1, $scope.op1); 
                            }
                            if($scope.op1=="-" && ($scope.op2=="*"||$scope.op2=="/"))
                            {
                                $scope.tempStr = -$scope.tempStr;
                                $scope.showInput1 = $scope.clac($scope.tempStr, $scope.showInput1, $scope.op2); 
                            }
                            alert($scope.showInput1);                           
                            $scope.op1="";
                            $scope.op2="";          
                        }
                        break;
                    case "+":
                    case "-":
                    case "*":
                    case "/":
                        if($scope.op1=="")
                        {  
                            $scope.tempStr = $scope.showInput1;
                            $scope.isClear=true;
                            $scope.op1=clickvalue;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $scope.tempStr = $scope.showInput1;
                            $scope.isClear=true;
                            $scope.op2=clickvalue;

                        }
                        break;
                    case "C":
                        $scope.showInput1 = "0";
                        $scope.isClear = false;
                        $scope.tempStr = "";
                        $scope.clacType = "";
                        break;

                    default :  
                        $scope.showInput1 = $scope.showInput1 == "0" ? "" : $scope.showInput1;
                        $scope.isContinue = false;
                        if ($scope.isClear) 
                        {
                            $scope.showInput1 = "";
                            $scope.showInput1 += clickvalue;
                            $scope.isClear = false;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            $scope.showInput1 += clickvalue;
                        }
                        //alert($scope.showInput);
                        break;
                }
                                                        }

                        $scope.clac = function(num1,num2,type)          {
                switch (type) 
                {
                    case "+":
                        return parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);
                    case "-":
                        return parseFloat(num1) - parseFloat(num2);
                    case "*":
                        return parseFloat(num1) * parseFloat(num2);
                    case "/":
                        return parseFloat(num1) / parseFloat(num2);
                    default:
                        return "lkl";
                        break;
                }           }     }




    };

  });
```

**HTML File :**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
        <script src = "AngularCalci.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="app">

        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

            <div>
                <textdir/>

            </div>
            <counter model="count"></counter>


        </div>

</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you see 0 and it is not changing at all. The reason is it has been initialized to 0 and its value was never set to other value after that.

You need to call the set function. You have missed to add this code.

```
sharedProperties.setProperty(value);
```

**UPDATE:**

I have observed one more problem with the way you are setting the value back to the textbox.
If you see this line in the controller, it executes only at the beginning. But your data may change anytime during the execution. So also need take care of this scenario.

```
$scope.showInput2 = sharedProperties.getProperty();
```

You may need to dig more about events($broadcast, $emit, $on) and watchers($watch) to solve this issue.